# Avatars and Image Manipulations in EE3?

Tags: ee3, image-manipulations

Is there a way to apply image manipulations to member avatars like you can with "regular" images? There's a line in the EE changelog that implies this is possible:

> Unified Upload Directories: Everything that used to be a special folder (Member photos, avatars, etc..) is now available in the File Manager and can use the usual file manipulations and other upload preferences.

However, I can't find those settings anywhere.

Or, is the only way to crop/resize avatars to use a third-party add-on?